# Facebook login is extremely slow

Tags: parse-platform

I am using the [ParseUI-Android](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android) library. When I try to login with Facebook, it takes between one and five minutes to complete. Note: with Twitter and regular accounts, the process is immediate.

Comment: It should not be like that, are you sure that's the case?

Comment: Share your code. Facebook login should not be slow if internet is working fine. You must be doing something else in your code

Comment: they have a sample app on git. if you think that the problem is in FB UI module then adapt it to your project's credentials and see its performance.

Comment: @LucasHuang @NSNoob I am using ParseUI-Android's `ParseLoginActivity` so I didn't really write any code. Here is how I set up the activity in my AndroidManifest https://gist.github.com/sandlerben/b59937b0c61f7ef830e5

Comment: u mean the response time it really long?

Comment: @LucasHuang I mean that when I click the "log into Facebook" button, it loads for one to five minutes before logging in.

Comment: @BenSandler might be a potential bug. Make an issue in the git then.

Comment: @LucasHuang I did [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/issues/114)